# Use Sublime3 SFTP on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sublimetext3

I am trying to edit file in EC2 remotely, I spend a while to setup the `config.json` but I still got timeout error.
I am using mac and I already `chmod 400` to `.pem` file

```
{
"type": "sftp",
"sync_down_on_open": true,
"host": "xxx.xx.xx.xxx",
"user": "ubuntu",
"remote_path": "/home/ubuntu/",
"connect_timeout": 30,
"sftp_flags": ["-o IdentityFile=/Users/kevinzhang/Desktop/zhang435_ec2.pem"],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out, Just in case anyone also have the same problem
I am use MAC OS
installed ubuntu

the config file is have is looks like

```
{
// The tab key will cycle through the settings when first created
// Visit http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings for help

// sftp, ftp or ftps
"type": "sftp",

// "save_before_upload": true,
"upload_on_save": true,
"sync_down_on_open": true,
"sync_skip_deletes": false,
"sync_same_age": true,
"confirm_downloads": false,
"confirm_sync": true,
"confirm_overwrite_newer": false,

"host": "xxxx.compute.amazonaws.com",
"user": "ubuntu",
//"password": "password",
"port": "22",

"remote_path": "/home/ubuntu/",
"ignore_regexes": [
    "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
    "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
    "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini"
],
//"file_permissions": "664",
//"dir_permissions": "775",

//"extra_list_connections": 0,

"connect_timeout": 30,
//"keepalive": 120,
//"ftp_passive_mode": true,
//"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
"ssh_key_file": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
"sftp_flags": ["-o IdentityFile=<YOUR.PEM FILE path>"],

//"preserve_modification_times": false,
//"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
//"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
//"remote_locale": "C",
//"allow_config_upload": false,
```

}

---

If you have permission problem :

```
chmod -R 0777 /home/ubuntu/YOURFILE/
```

this just enable read and write for all user

You may want to create a new user if above not working for you:
https://habd.as/sftp-to-ubuntu-server-sublime-text/
I do not know if this makes different , But looks like it start working for me for both user once Icreate a new user